# Unable to get Array from LocalStorage Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I made an array and adding list items to it dynamically, saving it to `localStorage`.

array is being saved in `localStorage` properly, but I am unable to get it back and append it to the DOM.

```js
const arr = [];

var cartItem = $(
  "<li class='newItem'> <p class='id'>1</p> <div class='details'><p class='name'>Orange</p><span class='weight'>20</span><span> /</span> <span class='avail'>In Stock</span> <p class='price'>10</p><a type='button' class='inc'>+</a><input type='text' class='quantity' value='1' ><a type='button' class='dec'>-</a></div> <a type='button' class='removeItem'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></li>"
);
var cartItem2 = $(
  "<li class='newItem'> <p class='id'>2</p> <div class='details'><p class='name'>Orange</p><span class='weight'>20</span><span> /</span> <span class='avail'>In Stock</span> <p class='price'>10</p><a type='button' class='inc'>+</a><input type='text' class='quantity' value='1' ><a type='button' class='dec'>-</a></div> <a type='button' class='removeItem'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></li>"
);

arr.push(cartItem, cartItem2);

localStorage.setItem("cartItem", JSON.stringify(arr));
var data = localStorage.getItem("cartItem");
var updatedData = JSON.parse(data);
$("#temp").append(updatedData);
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML for further understanding of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There issue in your code as of I found is:

1. Use `cartItem2= "<li class` instead of `cartItem2= $("<li class`, because array item cannot be a DOM element when saving to localStorage.

Check the below code, even though ***it is throwing error here in SO*** snippet, I checked in my local and ***it is working as expected***.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      var arr = [];

      var cartItem =
        "<li class='newItem'> <p class='id'>1</p> <div class='details'><p class='name'>Orange</p><span class='weight'>20</span><span> /</span> <span class='avail'>In Stock</span> <p class='price'>10</p><a type='button' class='inc'>+</a><input type='text' class='quantity' value='1' ><a type='button' class='dec'>-</a></div> <a type='button' class='removeItem'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></li>";
      var cartItem2 =
        "<li class='newItem'> <p class='id'>2</p> <div class='details'><p class='name'>Orange</p><span class='weight'>20</span><span> /</span> <span class='avail'>In Stock</span> <p class='price'>10</p><a type='button' class='inc'>+</a><input type='text' class='quantity' value='1' ><a type='button' class='dec'>-</a></div> <a type='button' class='removeItem'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></li>";
      arr = [cartItem, cartItem2];

      localStorage.setItem("cartItem", JSON.stringify(arr));
      var data = localStorage.getItem("cartItem");
      var updatedData = JSON.parse(data);
      $("#temp").append(updatedData);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="temp"></ul>
```